# PowerShell Graph-API Exit-Codes

Tags: powershell, try-catch, microsoft-graph-api, exit-code

Using Graph.Api to secure login to Azure DevOps.  My code works and does the correct outputs the problem is that when I am using task scheduler to run the task.  If the Key is invalid (I delete it to represent a key has expired) I am trying to catch the error and send that error code to Task Scheduler which in turn will be captured my SolarWinds and send an email with the error code and a reason for that error.

Here is my code

```
try {
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
}
catch {
    if ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode -eq "401") {
        Write-Host "Status Code Equals 401" -ForegroundColor Red
        $LASTEXITCODE = 20
        exit $LASTEXITCODE
    }
    else {
        CONTINUE
    }
}

$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
$TokenResponse
exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

If I delete the key from azure my script will write "Status Code Equals 401" in red.  With a valid key I get the $TokenResponse to print at the bottom of the screen with no problem.

I have tried it with a [bool] test if false or if true.  I have tried it with just a simple try catch.  I added the if statement trying to get it to not set the $LASTEXITCODE to 0.  I have tried setting the $LASTEXITCODE to 0 just before the final $TokenResponse.  Instead of returning 0 when the $tokenReSponse works I always get exit code 20.

Thanks in advance
Any help, ideas, opinions, or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use variable name `$LASTEXITCODE` as a user defined variable, because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#lastexitcode)

Comment: I have been using it up to this point with no problems.  In Task Scheduler the rest of my script works perfectly fine until I get to this part.  If the file is missing it produces the correct $LASTEXITCODE to result (0x2) or if the file string is not a valid string it will produce (0x10) this will produce the (0X20) code when the key is rejected by Azure because the key is no longer valid.  The problem is when the script run to completion with no other errors (file is there, string is valid and the key is accepted) it still returns the error code of (0x20).  Trying to figure that out.

Comment: We are going to use solar winds to track our scripts and if there is an error we will be notified to the problem prior to there being bigger issues down  the road.

Comment: That is exactly why you shoud not try to set `$LASTEXITCODE` yourself. Before the `try` set a self-defined variable to 0 (`$MyExitCode = 0`). Then in the `catch` set it to 20 (`$MyExitCode = 20`) Change the last line to `exit $MyExitCode`